# Pulling data from PI DataLink using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, osisoft

I am pulling huge amount of data from PI Server using VBA. I am using the following code:

```
**Dim myValues As PIValues

Set myValues = PIMath.GetInterpolatedValues_Point(inputPIPoint,
    PIMath.StringToPITimeFormat(StartDate),
    PIMath.StringToPITimeFormat(NextDate), "10s")**
```

What is the fastest way to copy all the values stored in MyValues to a column in a worksheet? I am using For Loop:

```
For k = 1 To myValues.Count

Worksheets("Sheet6").Cells(k, 2).value = myValues(k)
```

But it is extremely slowing down the process as I use multiple PI Tags and change time interval to 5 seconds.

Also, how can I set `myValues` to empty at the end of every full loop? This is what I am trying to do:

1. `MyValues` contains the data from Date 1st to 2nd
2. All the PI points in `MyValues` should be cleared
3. `MyValues` contains the data from Date 2nd to 3rd

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("B1").Resize(UBound(myValues)+1,1).Value = _
                                       Application.Transpose(myValues)
```