# Extract Data from Pivot Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I wrote the following vba code which is supposed to import any existing data from certain cells out of old.xlsx.
The cells are part of a pivot table and child cells of OE > location > qual in as their row.
The column is decided by the date which is input manually.

The strFormula is correctly formed. Printing it and manually inputting it into the a cell yields
a result. However using VBA always returns Error 2015.

I'm at my wits end. I manually tested every part of the code and it worked.
Its just the worksheet.Evaluate that seems to not work with the string.
Using wsA.Evaluate("B6") works just fine and saves the value into the current worksheet.

Is there some issue im unaware of or did I miss something?

```vb
Sub Einstellungen()

    Dim wbB As Workbook
    Set wbB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim wsB As Worksheet
    Set wsB = ActiveSheet


    Dim importColumn As String
    importColumn = InputBox("Input Column Name", "Column Name")
    Dim importColumnNumber As Integer
    importColumnNumber = Range(importColumn& 1).Column
    
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\old.xlsx")

    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Set wsA = wbA.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim date As String
    date = InputBox("Input Date of Export Column", "Date")
    
        Call copyData("A", "NY", "1", date, 4, importColumnNumber , wsA, wsB)
        Call copyData("A", "NY", "2", date, 4, importColumnNumber , wsA, wsB)
        Call copyData("A", "NY", "3", date, 4, importColumnNumber , wsA, wsB)
        Call copyData("A", "NY", "4", date, 4, importColumnNumber , wsA, wsB)
        Call copyData("A", "NY", "5", date, 4, importColumnNumber , wsA, wsB)

    wbA.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub

Function copyData(OE As String, location As String, qual As String, date As String, rowNumber As Integer, startColumnNumber As Integer, wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet)

        Dim strFormula As String
        strFormula = "=PIVOTDATENZUORDNEN(""Name"";$A$3;""OE"";""" & OE & """;""location"";""" & location& """;""qual"";""" & qual & """;""date"";""" & date & """)"
        
        Dim value As Variant
        value = wsA.Evaluate(strFormula)

        Dim columnNumber As Integer
        Select Case qual
        Case "1"
            columnNumber = startColumnNumber + 1
        Case "2"
            columnNumber = startColumnNumber + 2
        Case "3"
            columnNumber = startColumnNumber  + 3
        Case "4"
            columnNumber = startColumnNumber + 4
        Case "5"
            columnNumber = startColumnNumber + 5
        End Select
        
        Debug.Print strFormula
        Debug.Print value
        
        If Not IsError(value) Then
            wsB.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber ).value = value
        Else
            wsB.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber ).value = 0
        End If
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know if it's true for `Evaluate` but when entering cell formulas via VBA you always use comma as the separator, which may be different from your local separator (in your case it looks like you use ";")  You can try swapping out your ";" for ",".   You may also need to use the English function name `GETPIVOTDATA`

Comment: This did it for me.
So if you are using Excel in a language other than English: 
The string needs to follow the english naming convention, not the one that is used on your local program.

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer…

Comment: @Aldoraz - Using Evaluate with English formulas and commas is a good way to make your code work on any version of Excel, but if you'd prefer to use your language to make your calculations, the workaround in my answer is a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's true for Evaluate but when entering cell formulas via VBA you always use comma as the separator, which may be different from your local separator (in your case it looks like you use ";") You can try swapping out your ";" for ",". You may also need to use the English function name `GETPIVOTDATA`

Answer (score 0):

`Error 2015` can occur when the string you are passing is longer than 255 characters. This is a [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate#:%7E:text=The%20length%20of%20the%20name%20must%20be%20less%20than%20or%20equal%20to%20255%20characters.) limitation of the `Evaluate` function.

For example, if I run this on my machine (with the English version of Excel):

```vb
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=RAND()")
```

I get a random number.

However, if I run this:

```vb
    Dim MyFormula As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        MyFormula = MyFormula & "RAND()*"
    Next
    MyFormula = Left(MyFormula, Len(MyFormula) - 1)
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=" & MyFormula)
```

I get `Error 2015` since the formula is too long.

#### Workaround

To work around this, you could put the formula inside a cell, let Excel calculate it and then retrieve the value.

If I use my example above, it could look like this:

```vb
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        'Replace "CalculationSheet" with the name of your sheet
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("CalculationSheet")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "CalculationSheet missing"
    End If

    Dim rng As Range
    'Replace "A1" with the address range that you want to use for your calculation
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
    
    Dim MyFormula As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 100
        MyFormula = MyFormula & "RAND()*"
    Next
    MyFormula = Left(MyFormula, Len(MyFormula) - 1)
    
    rng.Formula = "=" & MyFormula
    rng.Calculate
    
    Dim CellValue As Variant
    CellValue = rng.Value2

    'Now you can use CellValue in your code
```