# reading data using GetPivotData

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Im trying to extract data outof a pivot table andkeep on getting runtime error 1004.
Im not very familiar with how pivot tables work so I am a bit blind.
"Variance - Hours" is the column that has the data, the Field is "PROJID" and filter value is "6726"

At present Im just trying to get the syntax correct so that I can expand on it.

```
Dim shtHOURs As Worksheet
Dim ptblHoursPivot As PivotTable
Dim rngHoursPivot As Range
Dim rngFiltervalue As Range

Set shtHOURs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hours")
Set ptblHoursPivot = shtHOURs.PivotTables(1)


rngFiltervalue = ptblHoursPivot.GetPivotData("Variance - Hours", "PROJID", "6726")
```

Comment: GetPivotData Is a worksheet function, not a method of a PivotTable object.  If you want to use it in VBA then look at using Evaluate() to run it

Comment: Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522551/extract-data-from-pivot-table-using-vba?noredirect=1#comment133258084_75522551

Comment: thanks Tim, so is there a method that I should be using in VBA to extract data? Id prefer to use the method as it is cleaner than using a worksheet function.

Comment: I don't do much of that type of thing, but maybe look at https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/ which shows how to reference various parts of a pivottable in vBA.

Comment: thanks Tim, that gives me some good direction referencing.

Comment: Not having much luck. everytime I either get an application error or

Comment: Not having much luck. Ive tried almost the technics in the Peltiertech link, plus used the evaluate() method. I check the object library. I either get an application error or "Unable to get pivotFields property of Pivot tables.

Comment: the data is imported via data connections. would that have an impact?

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying, along with a screenshot showing the value you're hoping to get?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to figure out Object in Excel VBA is to mark the code - and press F1 (help)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.getpivotdata?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm235139)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

A simples way to figure out the API on Pivot tables is also to record a macro.

1. Select a cell outside of the Pivot.
2. Start recording of macro.
3. Press '=' and select the cell in the Pivot.

I did this now on one of mine Pivot tables. Noticed that it recorded reference to the **cache of data**, and the **location** of the first cell in the Pivot table.

```
Sub RecordAPI()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=GETPIVOTDATA(""Order"",R51C1,""On Budjet (Y/N)"",""Yes"",""Mounth Act Fin / Bas fin"",""mar"",""Year Act Fin / Bas fin"",2022)"

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the record and the F1 method but none worked. I think the problem was that I needed to use rowlables to define what field data i needed. I ended up using  a different method using the addfilter method. its very clunky, but it is a temporary solution until new reporting software is installed.

Comment: Last time I used GETPIVOTDATA (to display progress this year in charts). I set up a help table where data and labels to chart correspond to the filed names in pivot. And to avoid the #Ref I used the ISERR function to return 0 if data of the mount was not present in the Pivot data. Good luck with new software. We have just shifted to Power Bi - and it feels like 'Ground hog day' every time I need to make a new type of report.